# FragmentTabHost - don't destroy fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can I tell `FragmentTabHost` to not destroy fragments(views) when I switch tabs? In one of the fragments I fetch some data from the Internet (or from a local database, depending on the situation), which takes a bit of time. I want to always keep this fragment in memory when it's posible.

I like the way `ViewPager` handles it with `setOffscreenPageLimit()` set to something bigger than `1`.

Comment: Why not use the "Tabs + Swipe" navigation pattern instead of `FragmentTabHost`?

Comment: I have a `ViewPager` in one of my tabs as well.

Comment: You can always store data in your "Activity" object because it's life is longer then the fragment's. I haven't used FragmentTabHost but in ViewPager it's a matter of adapter if it destroys fragments or not.  FragmentStatePagerAdapter vs  FragmentPagerAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution would be to use a [retained fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) without UI for fetching data and posting it to other fragments when data is there. The logic would be like this. Every fragment asks the retained fragment for data. If data is not there, they show "loading" state. If data is there, they show the data. If you want to have an event based communications between fragments, instead of calling fragments through interfaces, you can have a look at [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) event bus.